# page transition animation

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I started studying windows phone develop. I am now versed with page transitions. I looked through the standard library for animation transitions, such as Silverlight Toolkit for windows phone, but did not find anything like it. Tell me, how can I do the transition from page to page on the event, Flick, and that the first page went up, and the second followed immediately behind it without breaking.

image what be should:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/65664856/pagetransition_question.png

Comment: Why don't you want to use the toolkit?

Comment: I don't now how)
I try, but first passes the first page, and then comes the second, ie, they get a break. And I would like to do that they might go together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this [tutorial](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Navigation-Transitions-Step-By-Step-guide). It explains exactly how to use transitions in Windows Phone 7. However, the easiest is to use the toolkit (as explained in the tutorial)

You can also look towards this [toolkit](http://bewisephonecontrols.codeplex.com/) (Bewise Controls)

Comment: yes, I read this tutorial, but I can't understand, how can I do this animation